# react-native-reanimated and @rainbow-me/charts

Tags: dependencies

i am using react-native-reanimated and @rainbow-me/charts then gives me

TypeError: _ReanimatedModule.default.createNode is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:null in handleError
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in createErrorHandler
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in 
at node_modules@react-native\js-polyfills\error-guard.js:null in ErrorUtils.applyWithGuard
at node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:null in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.1.69:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in metroRequire
at http://192.168.1.69:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in global

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException

- ... 7 more stack frames from framework internals

use npx expo start-c but not solved i need help